# Normalização de dados em R

Tags: r

Estou tentando normalizar os dados e da o seguinte erro:

```
Error in if (colSd != 0) res[, i] <- (x[, i] - colMean)/colSd else res[,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

o código em R é esse:

```
# Modelo de Trinamento de uma Rede Multi-Layer Perceptron
library(RSNNS)

#carrega dados funcionando
Dados= read.delim("~/TrainingDataset.txt",
                  header = FALSE,
                  sep = ",",
                  quote = "\n\r")


# Embaralha os exemplos
Dados <- Dados[sample(1:nrow(Dados),length(1:nrow(Dados))),1:ncol(Dados)]

# Determinas os atributose a classe
DadosValues <- Dados[,1:30]
DadosTargets <- decodeClassLabels(Dados[,31])


# Divide o conjunto de dados em treinamento e teste uma proporcao escolhida
Dados <- splitForTrainingAndTest(DadosValues, DadosTargets, ratio=0.15)

# Normaliza o conjunto de dados para uma faixa de representacao igual para odos atributos
Dados <- normTrainingAndTestSet(Dados)

# Gera o modelo MLP (Multi-Layer Perceptron com SIZE neurônios) treinado.
model <- mlp(Dados$inputsTrain, Dados$targetsTrain, size=5, learnFuncParams=c(0.1), 
             maxit=50, inputsTest=Dados$inputsTest, targetsTest=Dados$targetsTest)


summary(model)
#model
weightMatrix(model)
extractNetInfo(model)


par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plotIterativeError(model)


# Caldulando as saidas prvistas pela rede MLP
predictions <- predict(model,Dados$inputsTest)

plotRegressionError(predictions[,2], Dados$targetsTest[,2])

# Monta a matrix de confusão entre a saída esperada e a saída calculada
confusionMatrix(Dados$targetsTrain,fitted.values(model))
confusionMatrix(Dados$targetsTest,predictions)
```

Uma pequena amostragem dos meus dados:

```
-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1
1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,0,-1,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,1,1,1,-1
1,0,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,0,-1,-1
1,0,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,0,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1
1,0,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,0,0,-1,1,1,0,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,1,1,1,1
-1,0,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1
1,0,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,0,-1,-1
1,0,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,1,0,1,-1
1,0,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,0,1,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,0,1,1
1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,0,1,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,-1,1,0,1,-1
1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1
1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,0,-1,-1
-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,0,0,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,0,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,0,1,-1
1,1,-1,1,1,-1,0,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,1,1,1,-1
1,1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1
1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,0,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,1,0,1,-1
1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,-1,1,1,-1,-1
1,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,1,1,-1,1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1
1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1
1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,1,1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,0,-1,1,0,-1,1
1,0,-1,1,1,-1,0,1,-1,1,1,1,1,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1
1,0,1,1,1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,0,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,0,-1,1
1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,1,0,0,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,-1,1,-1,1,1
1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,0,-1,1,1,1,1,0,0,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1
1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,0,0,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,1,0,1,1
1,-1,1,1,1,-1,0,1,-1,1,1,1,1,1,0,-1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,0,1,1
1,-1,1,1,1,-1,0,-1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,-1,1,-1,-1,-1
```

Alguma ideia de como corrigir?

Comment: Como não temos acesso aos teus dados, o exemplo não é reproduzível, então não tem muito como te ajudar dando uma resposta definitiva. Além disso, não há indicação de qual função está reportando este erro. Seria `normTrainingAndTestSet `? Uma sugestão que te dou é procurar por colunas nos dados que possuam valores constantes. Afinal, se os valores da coluna são constantes, seu desvio padrão é zero. Aí não faz sentido aplicar  uma fórmula do tipo `(x[, i] - colMean)/colSd` pois isto gera uma divisão por zero.

Comment: @MarcusNunes acrescentei uma amostragem só pra vc ter ideia de como são os dados, talvez ajude a me ajudar hahaha mas desde já, agradeço! e sim, a função com problema é a mencionada por vc

Comment: Em vez de fazer isto, rode do comando `apply(Dados, 2, sd)`. Isto vai te dar os desvios padrão de cada coluna do teu conjunto de dados. Se algum dos valores reportados estiver próximo de zero, então teus dados tem um problema. [Leia as páginas 3 e 4 deste artigo](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i05/paper) (cuidado, pdf) que ele dá algumas ideias de como resolver este problema.